# PHP: function argument reference for request data

Tags: php, function, post, pass-by-reference

I know that in PHP when you want the function parameters to reference target variables we use the ampersand `&` sign. But I can not figure out if it is still valid and reliable in the following scenario (where variables are gathered from a request).

```
$v1 = $_POST['v1'];

function filled(&$var) {
    return isset($var) && !empty($var);
}

if (!filled($v1)) // etc.
```

or even in this scenario:

```
$v1 = $_POST['v1'];
$v2 = $_POST['v2'];

function filled() {
    $args = &func_get_args(); // does this even take the references and not the values?
    foreach ($args as &$arg) {
        if (empty($arg) || !isset($arg)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

if (!filled($v1, $v2)) // etc.
```

Thanks in advance for clarification.

Comment: Sorry I failed to understand, why do you need reference in your example?

Comment: You're right actually. Anyway do you think the first line in second function does its job, at least?

Comment: A note: !empty() includes isset(), so no need to do both.

Comment: Doesn't `empty` return `true` for **0** and **false**? That's a big wall for me (applies to my own example, too).

Comment: @jack - PHP uses copy on write semantics so using references in these examples has no effect on memory usage.

Comment: @inhan `empty()` indeed returns true for `false`. If you don't want that, use just `isset()`. Using both with `&&` is the same as using just `!empty()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still valid since references don't care if the variables are user defined or come from PHP superglobals, but there are a couple of issues with your first example.

First, when you do `$v1 = $_POST['v1'];` `$v1` is now independent of the `$_POST['v1']` variable.  Any changes to `$v1` are not reflected in `$_POST['v1']` because you made a copy.

You could do: `$v1 = &$_POST['v1'];` to create a reference to it.

Second, your call to `isset` in the function will always return true.  `isset` is a special language construct, and not a function.  If `$_POST['v1']` is unset, `$v1` will still be set (but will be null) after the assignment of `$_POST['v1']` to `$v1`.

Also, as far as I know, `func_get_args()` doesn't support references, all the values it returns are copies of the original.

Does that clear up some of your questions?  If not, feel free to ask on anything you want clarified.

Comment: That was a good clarification, thank you. So for the second example, would using an array as the only parameter solve that reference issue?

Comment: Yes, for the second example, I think you would need to pass the array and receive it directly since func_get_args doesn't allow you to reference the actual arguments.  There is a comment on php.net/func_get_args by `mitko at edabg dot com` which shows how you can get references, but it is a bit hackish and I wouldn't use it in any released code.

Answer (score 1):

Scenario 1: it won't do what you want, since `$var` will always be set, as a function parameter. However, if you want to check if this parameter is not containing empty value (null,false, etc.) you can do `empty($var)`. No need to use `&` there.
What you want can be done as `!empty($_POST['v1')`. If you pass something to a function, it must have value, so using `isset()` in function will not do anything. Use either `array_key_exists` or `isset()` or `empty()` outside.

Scenario 2: `func_get_args()` does not need the `&`, drop it. `$arg` does not need it either and will always be set, so `isset()` check is useless, though only `empty()` is useful. As above, if you want to see if array key exists, use `isset($_POST['v1'])` or `!empty($_POST['v1'])`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was some valuable info.